# How object of parent class is created in Python?

Tags: python

I am not sure how object of a parent class is created in Python. Consider a following scenario.

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Animal is created")

    def eat(self):
        print("I am eating")

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, breed, name, spots):
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.spots = spots

    def bark(self):
        print("Woof! My name is {}".format(self.name))

my_dog = Dog(breed="lab", name="Sam", spots=False)
```

This does not print "Animal is created".

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Animal is created")

    def eat(self):
        print("I am eating")

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, breed, name, spots):
        Animal.__init__(self)
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.spots = spots

    def bark(self):
        print("Woof! My name is {}".format(self.name))

my_dog = Dog(breed="lab", name="Sam", spots=False)
```

Whereas this prints "Animal is created"

But in both the cases I am able to access eat() method of Animal class from Dogs instance (my_dog). This means Animal is created in both the cases. Then why I don't see Animals constructor getting called in case#1?

Comment: You need to use `super`.

Comment: The other question is asking how `super` works. This question is asking how `__init__` gets called. So, not a duplicate.

Comment: "But in both the cases I am able to access eat() method of Animal class from Dogs instance (my_dog). This means Animal is created in both the cases. " No, that is not how it works. Only a `Dog` object is created which *is* an `Animal` object, but there is only one instance. Instances have *access* to all methods in their class and the classes they inherit from. Remember, *methods belong to the class, not the instance*.

Comment: @RedCricket This is not a duplicate. Please read the question properly before acting on it.

Comment: @eyllanesc This is not a duplicate. Please read the question properly before acting on it.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Have you read the answers? Do you understand that when you inherit from a class you have to call the father's methods, and that does not mean that an object of the parent class has been created, but that the child needs to initialize some properties that the parent object I inherit it. For example, let's say that the Animal class has an attribute number of legs and that depends on how it walks, so as the Dog class inherits from Animal it has to initialize the number of legs that the parent class inherits.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal [cont.]  As the classes indicate they do not belong to the instance, they are part of the class.

Comment: But you have to understand that this question is the lines of whether parent object gets created automatically or not and this has nothing to do with the question you referred as duplicate of. I hope you understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling the parent class (`Animal`) `__init__` method in the `Dog` `__init__` method. To get a handle on the parent class you can use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). This is considered better practice than `Dog.__init__` since it doesn't explicitly require the name of the parent class.

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, breed, name, spots):
        super().__init__()
        self.breed = breed
        self.name = name
        self.spots = spots
```

Comment: My question is what if I dont. If I dont then also I am able to access parents method from childs object.

Comment: Sure you can still access parent methods but why would you expect the parents `__init__` to be called automatically?

Comment: If the parent __init__ is not called then how the parent object is created? As per my understanding __init__ is called anytime an object of a class is created.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal You can examine the order those methods are called using `Dog.mro()`

Comment: `__init__` just initialized an object - it doesn't create one. You might be thinking of [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal a paren't object *is not created*, and just because the `__init__` of the paren't class is called doesn't mean a parent-class instance is created. It's just that instances of classes that inherit from the parent class have access to those methods

Comment: You mean to say that I am accessing parent class methods and not the parent object method. If true, then this makes sense to me.